# Visual Studio 2019 Installer doesn't start

Tags: c#, c, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm using Windows 10 ver. 1909.    Installer hangs or does nothing.   No feedback.

Comment: When I tried to install with cmd command for offline installation its working but I want to install it with normal installer.

Comment: Where did you get the installer from?

Comment: from official website

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the issue was that I have downloaded and launched the installer to a user folder that contains non-English characters. Moving the installer to another folder fixed the issue. I´ve diagnosed the issue by looking into an installer log file in C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_professional__143315035.1628536728_decompression_log.txt.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly this problem.   Same version of Windows 10.  I tried both vs_community.exe and vs_professional.exe.  On a Microsoft Surface Pro 4.  The installer launches, a brief unpacking screen appears, that vanishes, and you're left with the task manager showing the installer but no user interface. I tried numerous different suggestions from Googling as well as the Collect.exe tool.  None of that helped.  Someone had a similar problem that hinted that a display could cause the problem.   My Surface had Duet installed, which allows you to use an iPad as a second monitor.   Uninstalling that allowed Visual Studio to install normally.  Apparently the Visual Studio installer is finicky about displays so if you have any unusual display drivers, or screen sharing utilities, they should be removed to allow installing.   I suspect that the driver or utility could be put back after installation.

Comment: Same here - I was connective via RemotePC and when I hooked up a monitor - there was a window that Remote PC was not showing.

Comment: Using the command line to install vs build tools may circumvent the monitor issue. See Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 Silent Install (How-To Guide) at https://silentinstallhq.com/visual-studio-build-tools-2019-silent-install-how-to-guide/. It didn't work in my case, though.

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to download this tool [Event Collect for visual studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/vs/support/can-get-visual-studio-installation-logs/), open your **CMD** as administrator,then run **Collect.exe** , after that you need to run your **visual studio installer** in the event of an error you will find and file named **C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\VSSetupEvents.txt** that you can check to see the error messages.

For more details you can check [documentation](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/vs/support/can-get-visual-studio-installation-logs/) .

Comment: [4/12/2020, 10:28:25] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0


[4/12/2020, 10:28:25] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x138a

Comment: @pybll did you find VSSetupEvents.txt file

Comment: @pybll do you another version of visual studio installed ?

Comment: no i didn't install before any version of vs on this pc

Comment: you can install VS2019 off line , you can follow the instruction in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: I said already I could download it offline but I want to solve this problem.

Comment: probably you should report the problem to microsoft team https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

My case is very embarrassing for Microsoft. I downloaded Visual Studio Setup and started it right away from browser. It was opened and then immediately closed. Nothing I could read on the Internet about this problem was not helping. Then I did one very simple thing. Moved setup from original location: C:\Users(user name)\Downloads, to c:\Temp -> worked like a charm. The thing is that my user name contains international characters (plus containing a space). All in all 21. century, full unicode support everywhere, but not in windows. Really embarrassing.

Comment: If you have any spaces on your username, the setup crashes. This method worked for me, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio 2019 Installer doesn't start**

I lost time about something I shouldn't have, I couldn't install vscode studio 2019 (I've installed it on multiple machines before).

I don't know exactly why, observed there might be something in my folder blocking it, I just moved it to a new folder and I could install. Good luck and don't make the same mistake as me

Answer (score 0):

And in my case, with both 2015 and 2013 installers on a Win 7, I had my user's folder not in C:\Users\ but on a netdisk. Which made it so that the installer would not run at all, no matter where I was running it from.
Creating a second user with their home folder on C:\ solved the problem.
That's Microsoft for you. Over 40 years of spearheading personal computing.